# how do i resolve deadlock in java

Tags: java, multithreading, deadlock

## Found one Java-level deadlock:

"Thread-13":
  waiting to lock monitor 0x000000000b297688 (object 0x00000000ef3c3528, a com.xxx.models.SCSToolScript),
  which is held by "Thread-11"

"Thread-11":
  waiting to lock monitor 0x000000000b297738 (object 0x00000000fd777fd0, a java.lang.Object),
  which is held by "Thread-13"

## Java stack information for the threads listed above:

"Thread-13":
    at com.xxx.models.SCSToolScript.isStopped(SCSToolScript.java:116)
    - waiting to lock <0x00000000ef3c3528> (a com.xxx.models.SCSToolScript)
    at com.xxx.actions.SCSToolManager.isStopped(SCSToolManager.java:352)
    - locked <0x00000000fd777fd0> (a java.lang.Object)
    at com.xxx.actions.ExecuteScript.checkStopped(ExecuteScript.java:1620)
    at com.xxx.actions.ExecuteScript.RCCommand(ExecuteScript.java:745)
    at com.xxx.actions.ExecuteScript.access$800(ExecuteScript.java:37)
    at com.xxx.actions.ExecuteScript$SCSThread.run(ExecuteScript.java:2112)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

"Thread-11":
    at com.xxx.actions.SCSToolManager.isPaused(SCSToolManager.java:346)
    - waiting to lock <0x00000000fd777fd0> (a java.lang.Object)
    at com.xxx.actions.ExecuteScript.checkPaused(ExecuteScript.java:1616)
    at com.xxx.actions.ExecuteScript.RCCommand(ExecuteScript.java:751)
    - locked <0x00000000ef3c3528> (a com.xxx.models.SCSToolScript)
    at com.xxx.actions.ExecuteScript.access$800(ExecuteScript.java:37)
    at com.xxx.actions.ExecuteScript$SCSThread.run(ExecuteScript.java:2112)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Found 1 deadlock.

Comment: A deadlock requires more than one thread. Where's the code for the other one?

Comment: I am sorry but I am not able to understand the code and thread dump posted. Probably, if you could right a SSCCE to demonstrate the problem, people can understand the issue better. Most of the times when I tried to write the sample program to demo the issue better, I understood what was wrong anyway :)

Comment: You have the call stack of both threads. You know that each thread has locked an object the other thread is trying to lock. You know what object each thread has locked. What more do you need? *Are you supposed to lock the object first or the script first?*

Comment: Deadlocks are programming bugs. The solution is to always acquire the locks in the same order.

Comment: Following EJP, we ended up building a framework that had annotations that specified the list of locks acquired to accomplish a task; which were acquired (automatically) in a consistent order.  If locking becomes problematic, then you need more clever data structures that avoid locking altogether (ie: functional/immutable style, CRDT, etc).